# Git merged branch receives commits unexpectedly

Tags: git, git-merge

I have 2 main development branches, `Release 1` and `Release 2`. `Release 1` is primarily being worked on where as `Release 2` contains any further lower priority development. `Release 2` has to be kept up to date with constant `Release`1 changes. To do this I checkout `Release 2` and do a pull from `Release 1`, then do a merge.

For some reason `Release 2` changes end up in `Release`1 (with all the development that is supposed to come in a later release). Why is this happening? 
 I've noticed strange fast-forwarding once I've merged `Release 1` into `Release 2` and doing a pull from my own local development branch. Any further commits to `Release 2` also end up in `Release 1` like they've been connected from now on.

I've come up with this diagram of what I'm trying to achieve

[image]

This happens in reality and `Release 1` is being corrupted by `Release 2` going into it. Instead of simply `Release 1` changes appearing in `Release 2`, Release 2 features also ended up in Release 1...

[image]

What can I do to safely put `Release 1` into `Release 2` and keep `Release 1` safe from `Release 2`? How can I do this merge correctly?

Answer (score 0):

> To do this I checkout Release 2 and do a pull from Release 1, then do a merge.

The `git pull` command is a combination of a `git fetch` and a `git merge`. This means that a pull automatically merges the new changes. If you try to do a `git merge` again, you will end up merging `Release 1` and `Release 2`, which is what is happening with you right now.

If you have a look at your code just after `git pull`, you will notice that the `Release 2` code is up-to-date. In fact, it is `Release 1` merging into `Release 2` and not the other way around. `Release 1` is polluting `Release 2`.
I hope this solves your problem. If any problem still exists, do comment down :)

Best.

Comment: Do you suggest I checkout Release 2, pull Release 1 and push recent changes to back into Release 2 and Release 1 won't be affected?

Comment: Yep. That's about it!

Comment: What if I did pull request from Release 1 into Release 2 and merged it. It breaks then too... For some reason the last commit says Release 2 into Release 1 even though the pull request is other way round.

Comment: If the graph above is accurate it sounds like your 'git pull' is configured to rebase rather than merge, so it might be replaying the local changes in Release 2 on top of Release 1, which is why you see a linear history instead of a merge commit appearing. You can perform the fetch manually instead and ask git-merge to do an explicit merge commit to avoid this.

Comment: Then you might be pulling it wrong. Doing this via git BASH would be more preferable than the GitHub UI(I think that is what you meant in the above comment)

Comment: I am simply trying to avoid any changes to the original Release 1. I simply want to transfer an out of date changes into Release 2 keeping the Release 2 features and Release 1 clean of Release 2 development.

Comment: Did you try what I mentioned above in the answer?

Comment: For some reason the pull doesn't find all the changes I did on Release 1. It finds some of them like it thinks Release 2 has the most up to date changes... It detected some changes in if statements but did not notice I've renamed some variables.